# convert PHP Accept-Language into more readable format

Tags: php, format, converters

PHP returns Accept-Languages ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) in a format like "en-US", "en", "de-AT". How can I convert them into a more readable format?

```
"en-US" -> "English USA"
"de-AT" -> "Österreichisch"
```

Is there a common way/function or do I have to look for a database (Whats the name of this format - is it ISO 639-1 with an optional region?!)?

Comment: I don't have a list for you with translations, but Accept-Language header has nothing to do with encoding. This is literally the language the client prefers.

Comment: I know that - I want to show the client preferred language - but in a readable format!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.3.0 or above and have internationalisation extension installed then you can use `Locale` class or the corresponding procedural function:

```
$dispname = Locale::getDisplayName('en-US');
echo $dispname;
```

will output

```
English (United States)
```

(Inlt extension: http://pecl.php.net/package/intl)

Answer (score 1):

As you might already have discovered, the codes you are using are ISO-3166, the easiest way seems to be converting from a webservice like this:

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('http://opencountrycodes.appspot.com/xml/');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$out = '$countries'." = array(\n";
foreach ($xml->country as $country)
{
    $out .= "'{$country['code']}' => \"{$country['name']}\",\n";
}
$out .= ");";

file_put_contents('country_names.php', $out);

?>
```

I found this code on http://dragffy.com/blog/posts/creating-a-php-array-of-iso-3166-1-country-codes